# How can I get tooltip overlay to render in correct position initially?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am writing a react bootstrap app where a button appears at the end of an animation. When the button first appears, I want a tooltip to appear next to it. Once the user hovers over and off the button, the tooltip should go away and re-appear whenever the user hovers over the button again. I've gotten this to work as desired, but when I position the button where I want it to be (fixed to the bottom of the screen), the tooltip initially renders in the wrong position (where the button was before being positioned).

I have created two simple examples to demonstrate this behavior.

In the first example, the button is positioned at the top of the screen and the tooltip behaves as this desire:

```
function Testing(){
    const refLink = useRef(null);

    const [overlayOpen, setOverlayOpen]  = useState(true); // Initially open
    const [textDone, setTextDone] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            setTextDone(true)
        },1000)
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    },[])
    return(
        <Container>
            <Row>
                {textDone ?
                    <>
                    <Button ref={refLink} onMouseOver={() => setOverlayOpen(true)}
                            onMouseOut={() => setOverlayOpen(false)}
                    >
                        <FaComment/>
                    </Button>
                    <Overlay target={refLink.current} show={overlayOpen}
                             onHide={() => setOverlayOpen(false)} rootClose placement={"bottom"}>
                        <Tooltip>
                            Submit a personal response!
                        </Tooltip>
                    </Overlay>
                    </>
                    : ''
                }
            </Row>
        </Container>
   )
}

export default Testing
```

The `textDone` state is set to true once the "animation" finishes. To simplify the example, I omitted the animation itself and recreated the delay with `setTimeout`.

The second example is identical except for the following .css class added to the Row element in which the button, overlay, and tooltip are nested inside of.

```
.fixed-button{
    position:fixed;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

With this addition, the button ends up where I want it, but the tooltip first appears at the top of the screen. Once I hover over the button, the tooltip moves to the correct position.

Here are some gifs of the two examples.

[Example 1 (tooltip behaving as intended but button not positioned in right spot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzne3.gif)

[Example 2 (button positioned where I want it but tooltip initially showing up in wrong spot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waLfi.gif)

My question is: how can I get the tooltip to initially appear in the correct position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! As pointed out by Thamy, the issue has to do with the `refLink` not pointing to the button until `onMouseOver` is triggered. The tooltip appeared in the wrong spot while `linkRef.current` was still `null`, and wouldn't reposition itself until `onMouseOver`.

I can't fully explain why, but moving the `linkRef` from the button component to the row component fixed my whole issue.

```
<Row className={"fixed-button"} ref={refLink}>
```

Answer (score 0):

The overlay is initially open as per `overlayOpen` state. Adding the `.fixedButton` class with `position: fixed` is getting the overlay and the tooltip to the placed in those "coordinates". More about CSS position [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

On your `<Overlay />` component you may want to pass the `placement` prop without the brackets like this `<Overlay placement="bottom" />`
So I'd initialize the state `overlayOpen` as `false` and have the `onMouseOver` event to set it as true like it already does. Then remove the `.fixedButton` class.

To finalize, the tooltip appears on the top first because the ref is initialized with null and at that time, in the first render, the `refLink.current` DOM node is null and not yet the Button. So the tooltip initialized to be open to a null ref point will just be placed on the beginning of the document. As you hover on the Button, the ref gets updated to that node and then `refLink.current` refers to the Button and the tooltip follows it.

> You might be familiar with refs primarily as a way to access the DOM. If you pass a ref object to React with `<div ref={myRef} />`, React will set its `.current` property to the corresponding DOM node whenever that node changes. [Documentation here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: HI Thamy, thank you for response. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but if I initialize the ```overlayOpen``` state as ```false``` the tooltip won't immediately appear next to the button as I want it to. Furthermore, if I remove the ```.fixedButton``` the button won't be positioned where I want it to. I'm not sure why I would want to do either of those things. Your third paragraph helped me understand what is going on in the first render, but I'm still not sure how to fix it. Is there a way to intialize ```refLink.current``` so that it points to the button on first render?